# Can a private transaction be a trigger condition?

Tags: etherscan, flashbots, private-transaction

So i was looking atthe launch of the meme coin $four and i noticed there was only one sniper that bought the coin in the same block. Now i know there were way more snipers but it suprised me none of them were in the same block.

This made me think maybe the liquidity add tx was a private transaction so it could only be seen after the block was validated. So how was there still 1 buy in the same block?

My thought is that the buyer made a bribed conditional transaction usimg flashbots using the liquidity adding as the trigger condition. Now ofcourse the buyer could not know the tx was in that block but the blockbuilder could see that, and to optimize profits it might have indeed put that buy after the liquidity addition and  triggered the condition and put the buy in the same block.

Any thoughts on this theory and if this could indeed be the case? I only learned about flashbots 2 days ago and im very intrigued on how it works!